# How to use the oscilloscope to show the average of the DC current?

Tags: oscilloscope

Recently, I made a buck-boost converter.
The figure shown below is the input current.
The input is a DC current (I used the programmable DC power supplier).
The frenquecy of the buck-boost converter is 20kHZ.
As you can see, the input current is not stable as a straight line.
In fact, it increases and decrease in every period of 50us.
The Max and Min current is about 3.97A and 3.2A.

[image]

However, when I zoom out the waveform to 2.5s time scale, the waveform is shown as below, which is not what I want.
I think this waveform is exactly same as the waveform at the 50us time scale.
The waveform that I supposed should be a straight line at 3.7A, which is the average value of the input current.

[image]

The protype of the buck-boost is shown as below.
And you can also see the current probe.

[image]

The oscilloscope that I used is TDS2024C.

[image]

I think the way that I used the oscilloscope maybe wrong.
Therefore, my question is how to use the oscilloscope to show the average of the DC current.

Comment: You are likely seeing an aliasing effect, I don't know about your specific model, try finding things about this in the manual (things like peak detect, increasing the sample rate and/or sample memory and increasing visual persistance might help too, if your scope has such features)

Comment: That is what I would expect to see for input current. It will not be constant, because it is switched on/off at 20kHz. You can set up the scope to perform an average or RMS measurement, use the _Measure_ button.

Comment: This is a four channel 2GSPS Tek. Please read the manual and find out how to setup an average measurement, on screen. That one is a freaking k$ machine, use it!

Answer (score 7):

When you zoom out, you are getting aliasing.  Even if you didn't get aliasing, you'd get a fat horizontal line that wouldn't tell you where within the fatness the average is.

What you need to do is low pass filter the signal before presenting it to the scope.  A simple resistor and capacitor should be good enough.  10 kΩ in series and 100 nF across the scope probe will attenuate the 20 kHz ripple to oblivion for your purpose.

Some scopes have measurement features that can do things like calculate the RMS from all the samples.  That may sound simple, but can be tricky too.  You have to make sure you have enough cycles on the screen or in the sample buffer (not necessarily the same thing) to get a good average and not have partial cycle artifacts, but not zoomed back so far that you get aliasing.

Comment: This is great advice. Especially the part "use the features wisely". Many people, once they learn the joys of a digital scope, just stop thinking. I would dare say that in the snapshot from OP there are enough cycles to neglect partial cycles artefacts. Some scopes also offer a gating function, so that the measurement is taken in between two precise time stamps: include a single (or integer number of) cycle(s) and you are good to go.

Comment: Hello, @Olin Lathrop, the low pass filter is a good idea. However, I used the current probe, as you can see in the third figure. Could you tell me how to use the low pass filter with the current probe, please.

Comment: @Lec: I already did.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1SkkB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- Put Two probes on same output  One AC coupled, other DC coupled
- then since scope  AC couple = 1~10Hz HPF on DSO measure Apk-Bpk = Vdc difference

  - Result is a LPF 1~10Hz difference or DC average
  - calibrated both probes with very short gnd leads so A-B on SAME point gives 0V flat line with any square wave test point and use same vertical scale
- OR on current probe save DC response and compare with probe set to AC response and compute difference A-Bsaved

Answer (score 0):

There's a reason they give you that slot-thing on the front panel.
You would export the data to a thumb drive, and do whatever calculations you need to do in Matlab (or Octave, if free software is your deal).